# Removing lines from a yaml block with Swift

Tags: swift, yaml

I aim at removing a Yaml key and value from a string variable, however I am failing.

### The MWE

```
let testMe = """
--- 
# Metadata
title: hum
author: jecatatu
email: jecatatu@gmail.com
---
This is more text outside the yaml block
"""
```

And the target is to have a string with:

```
let testMe = """
--- 
# Metadata
title: hum
---
This is more text outside the yaml block
"""
```

My code so far looks like:

```
var email = "jecatatu@gmail.com"
let emailline = "email: " + email
let document:String = testMe.replacingOccurrences(of: emailline,  with: "")
```

### Question

- The above is not working, that is not removing the email line from the yaml block, how can I remove both entire lines with author and email information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you place the following into a Swift 4 playground:

```
import UIKit

var testMe = """
---
# Metadata
title: hum
author: jecatatu
email: jecatatu@gmail.com
---
This is more text outside the yaml block
"""

var email = "jecatatu@gmail.com"
let emailline = "email: " + email
testMe = testMe.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n\(emailline)",  with: "")
print(testMe)
```

You'll get the following print of testMe:

```
---
# Metadata
title: hum
author: jecatatu
---
This is more text outside the yaml block
```

Note the author line, which your target doesn't include, but nor does your code and question state you wanted to get rid of.  Hope this helps!